# Auto-filling forms with facebook graph

Tags: javascript, facebook, forms, facebook-graph-api

I have two scripts written by my co-workers for auto-filling a form with information from the facebook graph-api. I am trying to figure out which has been coded in a more efficient style?

This is the first one.
http://jsfiddle.net/TcGGZ/30/

```
$('#account_get').click(function(){
    $.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/'+$('#facebook').val(), function(fd) {
        $('#id').val(fd.id);
        $('#name').val(fd.name);
        $('#first_name').val(fd.first_name);
        $('#last_name').val(fd.last_name);
        $('#link').val(fd.link);
        $('#username').val(fd.username);
        $('#gender').val(fd.gender);
        $('#locale').val(fd.locale);
    });
});​
```

This is the second one I am trying to decide about.
http://jsfiddle.net/VuY2b/46/

```
var facebook_account = '';

function fillForm() {
    facebook_account = $('#facebook').val();

    $.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/' + facebook_account, function(data) {
        var facebook_data = data;
        console.log(facebook_data);
        var inputs = $('form > input');
        for (var key in facebook_data) {
            for (var l = 0; l < inputs.length; l++) {
                if (inputs[l].getAttribute('name') === key) {
                    inputs[l].value = facebook_data[key];
                }
            }
        }
    });

}



var x = document.getElementById('account_get');
x.addEventListener("click", fillForm, false);​
```

Answer (score 0):

1st one is simple , 2nd one is complex.

According to me 2nd method is efficient because,If your websites form attributes are varying,second one checks for the correct matching attribues and fills it correctly.So i prefer 2nd.